# Passing a function to another function on a separate component in Ionic 2 or 3

Tags: function, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

a bit of a tricky one here. I've been trying to wrap my head around this one with no success. Ok, here it goes... I've got a function in a different ionic component set out like this:

**home.ts**

```
   playAudio() { 

    this.streamingMedia.playAudio('MY-URL');

    this.play = false;

    }

    stopAudio() {
    this.streamingMedia.stopAudio();

    this.play = true;
    }
```

Then I set up this boolean within the same home.ts file to toggle between the play and pause buttons

```
play: boolean = true;
```

Now, in my home.html file I have it setup as follows:

**home.html**

```
<div *ngIf="play">
<img src="assets/img/play.png" class="play" (tap)="playAudio()" />
</div>

<div *ngIf="!play">
<img src="assets/img/pause.png" class="play animated flip"     
(tap)="stopAudio()" />
</div>
```

Essentially what is happening here is, when I click the play button, play starts and then it shows the pause button. And likewise, when I click the pause button, play stops and shows the play button.

So, here is my problem, I'm trying to call the function in a different page/component. I want it to automatically play the stream when I open the page, I tried doing that by writing the same `playAudio()` function (as in the home.ts file) in the app.component.ts file where I need to set the function:

**app.component.ts**

```
play: boolean = true;

constructor() {
this.playAudio(); }

playAudio() {       
this.streamingMedia.playAudio('MY_URL');
this.play = false;
}
```

but when the page opens, the stream plays but I then don't have the option to set the pause button in place of the play button.

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: You can use [NavParam](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/) to send data from your `app.component.ts` to `home.ts` and use that data to show or hide play button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a suggestion: 
On your `playAudio()` function in home.ts, set `this.play = true` and vice versa in `stopAudio()`. In your html, do a checkpoint for `!play` instead of `play` and you have a sensible logic that can be understood by anybody else that reads your code.

For your dilemma, I'd suggest using an angular service [injectable](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable)

Basically, create your service. Decorate it as an injectable. Reference it as a provider in your app.module.ts and inject it into your app.component.ts's and home.ts's constructor. write and retrieve your `playAudio()` and `stopAudio()` in and from that service.

something like this:

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {StreamingMedia} from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';

    @Injectable()
    export class PlayerService {
    playing: boolean;
    audioUrl: string = //whatever url;

    //Inject your dependencies here
    constructor(public streamingMedia: StreamingMedia){
      this.playing = false;
    }

    playAudio(){
    this.streamingMedia.playAudio(this.audioUrl);
    this.playing = true;
    }

    stopAudio(){
    this.streamingMedia.stopAudio();
    this.playing = false;
    }

    }
```

reference this as a provider in your app.module.ts under providers section: `providers: [PlayerService]`

In your home.ts's constructor, inject the service you just made

```
constructor(public playerService: PlayerService){}
```

To use the `playAudio()` and `stopAudio()` function, just type
`this.playerService.playAudio()` and so on. Use the `playing` property of the service to tie up with the html.

I hope that clears things up with injectables.

In your app.component.ts, inject the service in the constructor as I showed before. Implement OnInit interface as

`export class AppComponent implements OnInit {}` and then create a `ngOnInit(){}` function where you can call the service's `playAudio()` function to start playing on initialization. And use service's `playing` property to again tie up with the UI.

Comment: Hi Anjil, thanks for your feedback! However, as someone that is new to ionic, "basically, create your service & etc..." isn't something basic to me :(  Are you able to provide an example please that I can perhaps follow to implement this feature. Thanks for your time, it is appreciated.

Comment: Apologies! I was under the impression that you have fiddled with ionic3 for a while and would like to give my directions a try. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the above. Can you please elaborate a bit on where the `this.playerService.playAudio()` should be placed, directly in the **home.ts** replacing the `playAudio()` as the tap function OR leave the `(tap)="playAudio()"` as is in home.html, then in **home.ts** have it as: `stopAudio() {
    this.playerService.playAudio();`?? Either way, the challenge I'm facing now is that I've tried all these options in the last couple of hours, and the only thing I can't get to work is the play property, the buttons don't change following your method above. I've tried almost everything

Comment: Hi Anjil, as a sidenote: in the **app.component.ts** file I'm merely just calling the function for a 3D Touch quick action, so when you use 3D force touch outside the app, it opens the app and should start playing the audio, its doing so now, as mentioned in my post above, but just as in the **home.ts / home.html** the play buttons are not alternating :(

Comment: do a *ngIf on this.playerService.playing

<div *ngIf="playerService.playing">Pause</div>
<div *ngIf="!playerService.playing">Play</div>

Comment: Hey Anjil! Thanks a lot!!!!! IT WORKED!!! I can't thank you enough... you are awesome! Thanks buddy!

Comment: glad to help! :)